# Long pending state of a pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argocd

I have an argocd pod from the https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/argo/argo-cd which is running in a long pending state. Others pods have easily gotten into running state while this specific pod: argocd-dex-server-668d5dd779-mw89l seemed to be taking its time. It's been 20m and it still in a pending state.

I tried debugging it with `kubectl describe` and based on the events nothing seems to be the problem. What could be the case here?

```
  Normal  Scheduled  8m54s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned gitops/argocd-dex-server-668d5dd779-mw89l to minikube
  Normal  Pulling    8m44s  kubelet            Pulling image "quay.io/argoproj/argocd:v2.6.7"
  Normal  Pulled     3m25s  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "quay.io/argoproj/argocd:v2.6.7" in 5m18.897752634s
  Normal  Created    3m25s  kubelet            Created container copyutil
  Normal  Started    3m24s  kubelet            Started container copyutil
  Normal  Pulling    3m24s  kubelet            Pulling image "ghcr.io/dexidp/dex:v2.35.3"
```

Also, it's not a problem with resources (as seen from the image below)
[image]

Comment: Are there no other status messages? If a Pod stays pending for that long it usually means that whatever resources it is expecting cannot be assigned to it

Comment: That was all of the events from that pod, unless you mean other stuff for a status message?

Comment: You could try running `kubectl -n <yournamespace> get pod <podname> -o yaml` or  `kubectl -n <yournamespace> get deployment <deployment> -o yaml` and interrogate the "status" fields therein.

Comment: Dex is responsible of auth service so I assume there is something wrong on the configmap used for authentication, but you should be more specific by showing the pod logs

Comment: Did it ever successfully pull the Dex image? Maybe a problem with ghcr?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your image has not been pulled yet. When you look closely to the output of the describe command you can see, that the status after `"Pulling image "ghcr.io/dexidp/dex:v2.35.3"` never switched to `"Successfully pulled image "ghcr.io/dexidp/dex:v2.35.3" in xxx"`.

Also, it took you 5m18s to pull the argocd image. This is an exceptionally long time. Check your bandwidth.